# How can i monitor the activities of the user

Tags: java

I'm developing a project "Information security system". in which i want to provide a feature of "session monitoring".
i simply want to create a table, in which each and every activities(which command is executed, which file opened, modified, login time, logout time, and every actions) of users are listed.
is there any API is available to implement this feature..???

Comment: You mixed too much in one question. There are APIs and tools for your tasks, but they are all very different: for example you can use file monitoring for files, for logon time you should look in system log.

Comment: Can you please suggest me some APIs for my task.??

Comment: Do you want to create a Java program monitoring the rest of the system, or do you only want a Java program, where the user can do actions inside it, which are then monitored?

Comment: @Paulo Ebermann, i want to create a java program that can monitor activities of the user on the whole system, not in a single java programm.

Comment: This is not really doable with Java itself - you will need access to many system dependent functions for this, and maybe also super user privileges. Better look at frameworks in other languages (depending on your system) - or you may even need to patch the system kernel. You may then connect a Java GUI for evaluations (or a Java server for collecting the data) with your observation program.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little bit vague, but it sounds like a job for [Aspect oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming)

Comment: The question is about finding an API not a paradigm for the project.

Comment: As I said: the question is vague, and I'm not really sure if @NiKx wants an api. If an API is really wanted, you are correct that my answer is wrong and also @Andrey's comment is correct.

Comment: Yes @Ocaso i need some APIs and tools which i can combine with my project coding to provide the "Monitoring" feature.